# Substring to retrieve parts of a string

Tags: t-sql, substring

I have a field in my database that has a datatype of varchar(10). Here I am saving Hour:Minute AM/PM. I am letting user select hour, minute, am/pm from dropdowns, I concatenate it and save it to table like this:

```
01:00 PM
```

What I'm trying to do, is seperate this string so that I am able to extract the Hour, Minute and PM or AM. The first thing that came to mind is Substring, and so here's what I've been attempting:

```
select substring('01:00 PM',1,2) as [Hour] 
Select substring('01:00 PM',4,5) as [Minute] 
select substring('01:00 PM',7,8) as [AMPM]
```

For Hour, I am getting the correct value which is `01`. For Minute, I am not getting the correct value, it is showing me `00 PM` and then for AMPM I am again getting the correct value of `PM`. Any reason why I'm getting the wrong value in Minute? Or is there possibly an alternative way I can get the same results, as in `01, 00, PM`

Comment: Never store date/time values in varchar columns, use proper data types!

Comment: "`DATE` is far more efficient for search/sort/join/group/between than `VARCHAR` so `VARCHAR()` isn't even an option" See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208724) answer.

Comment: @jarlh I need to be able to let user pick a specific minute, so i have dropdowns for minute, hour and AM/PM - any way of doing this using Datetime field (which I suppose you are suggesting?)

Comment: To jarlh's point, you could store the data as datetime (assuming SQL Server) but use DATEPART() to present minute/hour/etc. values to your users for selection.

Comment: @Koosh how your users create inputs on a field for doing data entry or search should have no bearing on how you store that data in the database. You should be storing and manipulating these times as `time` types both in your database and your application code. Otherwise you risk having a meeting set for `13:76 AM`

Comment: @alroc well i set up my hour to only display 00-12 and minute for 00-60 so that would not be possible. Plus it wasn't entirely my idea to do this as varchar but I'm open to changing it

Comment: @Koosh "not possible" unless the user bypasses the HTML form and submits an HTTP request directly. There is no reason to _not_ store this data as the appropriate `time` type in your database and every reason to do so.

Comment: @alroc i understand that, but I need it to be displayed in 3 textboxes HOUR MINUTE AM/PM. This is a direct requirement from requestor

Comment: @Koosh you'd do that transformation in your application code, not the database itself. Construct an appropriate object from the inputs, then execute a query to perform the `insert` statement. Then do the reverse on `select` if you need to render it back to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select substring('01:00 PM',1,2) as [Hour] 
Select substring('01:00 PM',4,2) as [Minute] 
select substring('01:00 PM',7,2) as [AMPM]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just convert this to a time?

```
select convert(time, '01:00 PM')
```

You can use `datepart()` or `datename()` to extract the hour and minutes.  Use a 24-hour clock, so AM/PM is not needed.

The user can choose the time as *time* value.

You can also add this into the table:

```
alter table t add col_time as (try_convert(time, col));
```

The `time` should be easier to work with using the correct type, rather than as a string.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd argument of SUBSTRING is the number of characters to select, so for Minute, it should be

```
Select substring('01:00 PM',4,2) as [Minute].
```

Also, your AMPM should be changed to

```
select substring('01:00 PM',7,2) as [AMPM]
```

.  You're getting the correct result for AMPM because it happens to be the end of the string, but your current statement would pull 8 characters starting at position 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below also for minute

```
DECLARE @textval NVARCHAR(30),@STR nvarchar(200)
SET @textval = '01:00 PM'
SET @STR = STUFF(@textval,1,3,'')
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(@STR, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @STR), 8000),
       PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(@STR, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', @STR), 8000) + 'X') -1)
```